# Is direct map in the useState hook an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs

So let's say I have like a list of todos, for example.

```
const [todos] = useState<Todo[]>([
  {
    id: 1,
    content: 'Todo #1',
    isDone: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: 'Todo #2',
    isDone: false,
  },

  // ... and so on
]);
```

As you can imagine, it can take a lot of space. It's a lot of copying and pasting, pretty much. The only truly unique thing is the `content`. Would it be an anti-pattern to do it like this?

```
const [todos] = useState<Todo[]>(
    ['Todo #1', 'Todo #2'].map((content, i) => ({
      id: i + 1,
      content,
      isDone: false,
    })),
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not at all, go for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely, the state can be initialed with a result of map call. It's not an anti-pattern.

But, *if* the return value inside `useState` is computationally expensive, you can [Lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
  return initialState;
});
```